# stringstream and binary data

Tags: c++, binary, stringstream

What is needed (some method overrides?) in order to read/write binary data to/from std::basic_stringstream?
I am trying the following code, but it does not work as I supposed:

```
std::basic_stringstream<uint64_t> s;
uint64_t a = 9;
s << a;
uint64_t b;
s >> b;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

but I get "0" printed (built with GCC).

Comment: There is no built-in specialization of  `std::char_traits<uint64_t>`. You won't be able to instantiate `std::basic_stringstream<uint64_t>` until you provide one. Now, what is it you are trying to achieve? Your code doesn't make much sense to me. [It prints `9`](http://rextester.com/BDPZD89619) if you just use plain vanilla `std::stringstream`, but there's no "binary data" in there, and it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: no offense, but afaik `basic_stringstream` is for those that know what they are doing. What do you actually want to achieve? I am almost sure that `basic_stringstream` isnt the right tool for it

Comment: Are you trying to convert a 64-bit decimal number to a textual binary representation, such as "1001" for 9?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to read/write *binary* data you can't use `<<` or `>>` you need to use the `std::stringstream::read` and `std::stringstream::write` functions.

Also you need to use the `<char>` specialization because only `char` can safely alias other types.

So you could do it this way:

```
std::stringstream ss;

std::uint64_t n1 = 1234567890;

ss.write((char const*) &n1, sizeof(n1)); // sizeof(n1) gives the number of char needed

std::uint64_t n2;

ss.read((char*) &n2, sizeof(n2));

std::cout << n2 << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
1234567890
```

Comment: why can't you use `<<` `>>` with binary stream?

Comment: @Tellegar Both `<<` and `>>` are *formatting* operations - that modify/change the data being read or written. Binary streams need to be transmitted and received unchanged.